# What does "dread deeds" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In "The Gita according to Gandhi" p.9:

> "while the wolf-bellied Brhima of dread deeds sounded his great conch
>   Paundra."

I'm not sure of the meaning of "dread deeds", would it be : "the wolf-bellied Brhima of greatly feared actions" ?

→ According to http://www.asitis.com/1/15.html an in-context translation could be made as "the voracious eater and **performer of Herculean tasks**"

We might translate "dread deeds" as "(performances) (regarded with great awe)"

Comment: It looks like it's the same as what I found in another book, which the correct spelling should be ***Bhima*** (some write this name as "Bheema"). I found a similar text (also by Gandhi, I believe) in [The Bhagavad Gita According to Gandhi](http://books.google.com/books?id=HUbUcXcXES8C&pg=PA5), "(15) Hrishikesha [Krishna] blew the Panchajanya and Dhananjaya [Arjuna] the Devadatta, while the wolf-bellied Bhima of dread deeds sounded his great conch Paundra."

Comment: See also: http://www.asitis.com/1/15.html

Comment: @MaulikV: Whether the name is spelled correctly or not seems irrelevant to the question, which is about the meaning of "dread deeds".

Comment: The phrase "dread deeds" means exactly what the dictionary tells you it does; the context (including the spelling of *Bhima*) does not affect the meaning at all.

Comment: @oerkelens Yes I missed it. Vote retracted and upvoted.

Comment: Is this normal in Indian English?  The phrasing sounds odd in American English although I can surmise the meaning from the individual words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, Gandhi's getting his Western poetry thing on here.

The word **dread** modernly refers to a feeling of frightened foreboding.  As with most feelings, it can be used as a noun to refer to the feeling itself, and it can be used as a verb to refer to the experience of feeling the feeling.  Generally when we employ **dread** to describe something, we use the verb form **dreaded**, because that's how we do it with feelings in English, e.g. "feared", "loved", "hated".

Thing is, there's a mostly archaic meaning of **dread**, which means "awe-inspiring".  (I understand this use is still current in Jamaican Patois, but don't take my word on it.)

So **dread deeds** can be taken to mean **awesome deeds**, which is more grammatical than the **terrifying deeds** we might extrapolate from the modern sense of **dread**.  Regardless, the upshot seems to be "dude had a badass rep on the street."

Other textual evidence, in particular **wolf-bellied**, which I totally failed to parse right until I saw the other translation ("You mean furry and likes to be petted?"), is meant as as synonym for **voracious**.  Or more precisely, that's a ***[kenning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenning)*** for voracity.  Since Gandhi is using a type of figure of speech that was, you know, last popular in English [a thousand years ago, more or less](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf), it would seem to mean that he wants the archaic interpretations, that he means to communicate to the English reader the great antiquity of the work by invoking the reader's memories of ancient English literature. (Which is kinda neat.)

Comment: The text was written in Gujarati during the late 19th century, so it's not appropriate to say Gandhi (the author, who is not Mahatma Gandhi the political figure) is writing in the style of western poetry or that the work possesses great antiquity.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName → In fact the Bhagavad Gita was written between 4th century BCE and 4th century CE. So Codeswitcher's answer makes sense!